# Is there an openly available implementation of the Hopcroft's DFA minimization algorithm?

Tags: dfa, automata

Ditto. Java or C# would be best, but any imperative language will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can find it in Java here:
http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~berstel/Lothaire/AppliedCW/ProgrammesJava/BibliJava/